grpc work with grpcurl but not working with java integration
We have a customer that we have to connect their grpc services. We can create jwt token from their server. When we use this jwt token with grpcurl, we can get response successfully, but when we trying to connect via java8 implementation we get this error;
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Unauthorized

please help us to cover problem.

please post the Java program that helps get the token. Also please run the grpcurl command in verbose mode and post the output. Don't forget to post the grpcurl command as well :).
please provide the full stack trace of the java program.
